# Asp.net url is not working url: 'insert.aspx/doSomething',

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I write url in AJAX it is not working. It is not post the value in to the  `doSomething(string fname,int age)` method I wrote the method `addProject()` with in method I wrote AJAX funtion send the data to insert.aspx/doSomething but it is not working.

**AJAX**

```
 function addProject() {
            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: 'insert.aspx/doSomething',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { fname: $('#fname').val(), age: $('#age').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");

                },

                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            }
```

**insert.aspx**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string doSomething(string fname,int age)
    {      
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
        string sql = "insert into record values('" + fname + "','" + age + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
         return "Sucess";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think realized that I had this line in the ajax post wrong:

```
data: { fname: $('#fname').val(), age: $('#age').val() },
```

It should be:

```
data: "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val()+ "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}",
```

As well as the WebMethod to:

```
public static string AddTo_Cart(string fname, int age)
```

i wish this resolved your problem.

Comment: you are best developer sir

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap those two property in a class then it will work.
Here UserClass is custom class which contains fname and age property

```
public class UserClass
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static string doSomething(UserClass obj)
{      
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
    string sql = "insert into record values('" + obj.fname + "','" + obj.age + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
     return "Sucess";
}
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in console   insert.aspx/doSomething:1  record is not added sir

Comment: Wrap the key and value inside single quotes before calling AJAX function and receive both properties in webmethod as you were doing. If you have change server side parameter to class, you have to send an object from AJAX.

Comment: Your final data request should look like: { fname: 'XYZ', age: '50' }

Comment: can you write the full code sir it is easy to understand

Comment: data: { fname: 'XYZ', age: '50' }, i test in ajex like this but data is not added sir